# Struggle: If-else statement in C ( I'm a totall beginner and I've just learned C for 2 weeks )

Tags: c, if-statement

My teacher gave us this homework about if-else statement and I don't know why but my code only passed 3 out of 5 testcases, Can your please help me fix the problem. Thank you so much and hope you have a great day!

**Question:**

Calculate the parking fee based on the pick-up time.
The regulations for a motorbike parking lot are as follows:

- Do NOT park overnight.
- Pick up the vehicle before 18:00, the ticket price is 5000 VND/vehicle.
- Pick up the vehicle from 18:00 onwards, the ticket price is 8000 VND/vehicle.
  write a program to input the entry and exit times in the format HH:MM.
  If the entry time is greater than the exit time (input time error), then output the value -1.
  If the entry time is equal to the exit time, then output 0.
  Otherwise, calculate according to the formula above.

```
INPUT
12:00 13:35
OUTPUT
5000

INPUT
12:00 11:35
OUTPUT
-1
```

This is my code, I tried fixing it but it didn't workout

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{   int hour1, min1;
    int hour2, min2;
    scanf("%i%*c%i", &hour1, &min1);
    scanf("%i%*c%i", &hour2, &min2);
    
    if (hour1<24 && hour2<24 && min1<59 && min2<59){
         if (hour1 == hour2 && min1 == min2) 
             printf("0");
         if (hour1>hour2)
             printf("-1");
         else if  (hour1 == hour2 && min1>min2)
              printf("-1");
         else {
              if (hour2<18)
                  printf("5000");
              else if (hour2>18)
                  printf("8000");
            }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Imagine what happens if you pick up your vehicle at `18:30`. So `hour2` is neither `< 18` nor `>18`

Comment: `min1<59 && min2<59` wants to be `min1 < 60 && min2 < 60`... Off by one...

Comment: When the question says, "output the value -1", I would assume that it means to have the return value of the code as `-1` rather than printing `-1` to the screen.

Comment: The most valuable thing to learn in engineering is always to question the requirements. For example "Do NOT park overnight" and "Pick up the vehicle from 18:00 onwards" contradict each other. The requirements do not specify when "night" begins, so the program cannot be written without clarifying that requirement.

Comment: @MattPitkin when the question mentions "input" and "output" I'd expect the testrunner to write into stdin of my application and read from the stdout of my application. Because how would it otherwise test for non-numerical output?

Comment: You missed the case that `hour1 == hour2` but `min1 > min2`

Comment: You ignore the return value of `scanf()` at your own risk - especially if something does not act as expected....

Comment: @MattPitkin I doubt a return value of `-1` would be preserved as the exit status of the program, but it depends on the system. On Linux it would be converted to an exit status of 255.

Comment: Imagine if I give time as "-1:-1".

Comment: `if (hour1>hour2)` should be `else if (hour1>hour2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some small things to improve this and why:

- First and foremost: don't you dare to not use spaces between operators - this makes code unreadable when you try to get a fast impression. Use `a < b` instead of `a<b`.
- Generally try to be very explicit in C. Do not try to cram your code in as little space as possible. As you will read your code more than you will write it - readability is the top priority.
- The only error handling in your code is the one you write. So as suggested above by *kiner_shah* check the return of every function: `if (scanf(...) != 2) { do error handling }`. This also helps with debugging, if you have to find an error. You can find the returns of standard functions [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) for example.
- That is more of a tip from me personally. The less you check in one `if()`, the easier it is to see if all states are handled.
- If you check multiple states with `if()` be very careful if you do not use a final `else()`. Even if you are pretty sure that you got most of the possible cases, an `else()` might still be useful as error-handling. That was the case in your example above.

```
    if (hour1 < 24 && hour2 < 24 && min1 < 59 && min2 < 59){
        if (hour1 == hour2) {
            if (min1 == min2)
                printf("0");
            if (min1 > min2)
                printf("-1");
        } else if (hour1 > hour2) {
            printf("-1");
        } else {
            if (hour2 < 18) {
                  printf("5000");
            } else {
                  printf("8000");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the check when out time hour is equal to 18.
I have added some more checks and improved it a bit, read the code comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    // Time can't be negative - use unsigned
    unsigned int in_hour, in_min;
    unsigned int out_hour, out_min;

    // As suggested, check for return value of scanf
    if (scanf("%u:%u", &in_hour, &in_min) != 2)
    {
        printf("Error during input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (scanf("%u:%u", &out_hour, &out_min) != 2)
    {
        printf("Error during input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //printf("In time: %02u:%02u\n", in_hour, in_min);
    //printf("Out time: %02u:%02u\n", out_hour, out_min);

    // 00:00 is the min allowed time value
    // 23:59 is the max allowed time value
    // NOTE the NOT sign '!'
    if ( ! (in_hour <= 23 && in_min <= 59 && out_hour <= 23 && out_min <= 59))
    {
        printf("Invalid in or out time\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (in_hour > out_hour || (in_hour == out_hour && in_min > out_min))
    {
        printf("-1\n");
    }
    else if (in_hour == out_hour && in_min == out_min)
    {
        printf("0\n");
    }
    else
    {
        if (out_hour < 18)
        {
            printf("5000");
        }
        // No need to check for >= 18, just use else
        else
        {
            printf("8000");
        }
    }
}
```